# Jquery ajax data

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, qtip

I am using the qTip plugin to post a imdb URL to an IMDB grabber script and display movie info on that url.

Everything works until I have more than one qtip on the page.

What i need to do Is only post the data of the image that is being hovered. This is the code should make a bit more sense then me.

Script -

```
var link = $("#link").val();
var imdbLink =  { "link" : link };  // note change to data...

$('.moviebox').each(function() {
    $(this).qtip({
       style: { name: 'light' },
       content: {
         method: 'GET',
         data: imdbLink,   // you could make this { "link" : link }
         url: '/bin/imdb/imdb.example.php',
         text: '<img class="throbber" src="/images/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." />'
       },  
       position: {
             corner: {
               target: 'bottomright',
              tooltip: 'bottomleft'
            }
          }
    });
    });
```

html--

```
  <div class="moviebox rounded"><a href="#">
  <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_mySxtRcQIag/S6deHcoChaI/AAAAAAAAObc/Z1Xg3aB_wkU/s200/rising_sun.jpg" />
  <form method="get" action="">
    <input type="text" name="link" id="link" style="display:none" value="http://us.imdb.com/Title?0107969"/>
 </form>
  </a></div>



  <div class="moviebox rounded"><a href="#"><img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_mySxtRcQIag/S6dUoGd4_TI/AAAAAAAAObM/4Mbohcy0Owo/s200/grumpy_old_men.jpg" />
   <form method="get" action="">
    <input type="text" name="link" id="link" style="display:none" value="http://us.imdb.com/Title?0107050"/>
 </form>
 </a>
```

You will see that both inputs have the same ID which is causing an issue. how would I get around this keeping the IDs the same????

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution is to use class instead of id.  Besides that, ID are meant to be unique, shouldn't use them in more than once on the same page anyways.

Comment: Changed it to a class. Hasn't helped the script still doesn't know which one to choose

Comment: Well, you probably have to use .each() to loop through them.  I think the easiest is just to add the $('.link').val() inside your $('.movie').loop.  If you don't mind redundancy, I got a silly method that might work.  Take out the first 2 lines, instead $('.link').attr('id',function(e){ return 'id'+e; }  Inside your $('.movie').each loop, $('.movie').each(function(x){ ... data:{ 'link: '+$('id'+x).val(); }, ...}

Let's see if that works.

Comment: you need some way to differentiate between them. mon is correct in that IDs should be unique (if they aren't, jQuery will use the first one it encounters, i believe)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.moviebox').each(function() {
   var imdbLink =  { "link" : $(this).find("input.link").val() };
   $(this).qtip({
      // qTip code
   });
});
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful.